# Protractor test fails on async polling (Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

Tags: angular, protractor

I have an angular component which basically shows a list of database objects. Since they can be in different states, this is shown as a tab view in angular, where each tab contains all objects in a specific state. Each object has the id from the backend associated with them as `id=1`. If the state of the object changes, an object moves from one tab to another.

The structure of the html looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/eKNgEnDs).

This is implemented using polling and is run outside the angular zone ([because of this issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/49)):

```
function startPollingObjects() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() =>
        setInterval(() => {
            this.refreshObjects();
        }, this.pollingFrequency)
    );
}

function refreshObjects() {
    // async call to the backend
    api.getNewObjects.then( data =>
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            // Run inside zone as the inputs are changed here 
            // so change detection is triggered

            // change data accordingly
            this.list = [];
            for (const row of data) {
                if (!this.list[row.objectState]) {
                    this.list[row.objectState] = [];
                }
                this.list[row.objectState].push(row);
            }
        });
    )
}
```

What I want to test now, is if an object changes its state and moves from one tab to the other.

- Creating the object from the UI (initial state is `state1`)
- Navigate to the list
- iterating through the state1 tab to find the object with the greatest id (which is the newest created object) *
- wait for the object to appear in the other tab (`state2`) **

*

```
let lastCreatedObjectId = 0;
await element.all(by.xpath(`//div[@id = 'state1']/*`)).then( async elements => {
        for (const object of elements) {
            await object.getAttribute('id').then( objectId => {
                lastCreatedObjectId = objectId > lastCreatedObjectId ? objectId : lastCreatedObjectId;
            });
        }
        return null; // required as I'm getting this error otherwise https://pastebin.com/AasAZrVY
    });
```

**

```
import { by, element, ExpectedConditions as until } from 'protractor';

const object = element(by.xpath(`//div[@id = 'state2' and ObjectAngularComponent/@id = '${lastCreatedObjectId}']`));
    // clicks on the tab to select it
    listObjectStatePage.selectTab(ObjectState.State2);
    browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(object), 20 * 1000).then( () => {
        expect(object).toBeTruthy();
        return null; // required as I'm getting this error otherwise https://pastebin.com/AasAZrVY
    });
```

-- Now things get interesting --

As soon as the element appears in the list, proctractor throws me the following error.

```
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
at Timeout._onTimeout (/path/to/project/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4281:23)
at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5)
```

Edit: `return null; // required as I'm getting this error otherwise` https://pastebin.com/AasAZrVY

Comment: why do you ``await element.all`` ?

Comment: Because the `lastCreatedObjectId` would be undefined if I don't

Comment: I'm not sure you can use ``await`` and also ``then()`` on the same function, also ``lastCreatedObjectId`` is defined since you initialize it at ``0``

Comment: I need to get the object with the highest id before I'm waiting for it to appear in the other tab. So even if it's 0 it would not work ... It can also be that this approach is the wrong one, but I can't find another way to test this ...

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm struggling with this for weeks, for now commenting out the e2e tests that fail, but that cannot be the solution.

Comment: Nope, I gave up testing onto this